# Shares with og:video links instead of plays in Facebook app (ios)

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got a web page i want to share on Facebook. 
The page has a set of Open Graph meta datas, including the og:video setup:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/mypage />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Site"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="My Description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/mymovie.jpg" />
<meta property="og:video" content="https://example.com/mymovie.mp4"/>
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://example.com/mymovie.mp4" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="video/mp4" data-content-type="dynamic">
```

When shared, and browsed in a web browser on desktop, the video gets embedded - just as expected. However, when browsed inside the IOS Facebook app (iPhone 7, latest version), a click on the play button results in a navigation to the og:url (or maybe rather the shared url, which is the same).

How come?